# Form processing of several fields

Tags: php

I have a form with more than 40 fields (input, textarea, select ...) and in this form I have fields that have the same processing conditions example:

"customer code":

```
if(isset($code_p_client)))
{
  if(preg_match('#^[0-9]{5}$#',$code_p_client))
  {       
    $code_p_client=htmlspecialchars($code_p_client);
  }
  else
  {
     $erreur="Le champ code postal client n'est pas valide";
  }
}else
{
  $code_p_client=null;
}
```

shop code :

```
    if(isset($code_p_boutique)))
{
  if(preg_match('#^[0-9]{5}$#',$code_p_boutique))
  {       
    $code_p_client=htmlspecialchars($code_p_boutique);
  }
  else
  {
     $erreur="Le champ code postal boutique n'est pas valide";
  }
}else
{
  $code_p_boutiquet=null;
}
```

my code functions perfectly, the problem is that currently I treat each field on its own: '((40 fields a lot of code that is repeated).

Please someone could give me some idea on how I can simplify the processing.

Comment: make a function so you can re-use most of the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your case you may do something like this

```
<?php

$code_p_client = $_POST['code_p_client'];
$code_p_boutique = $_POST['code_p_boutique'];
$another_var = "12345";
//...

$apply1 = function(&$v) {$v = htmlspecialchars($v);};

$arProcess = [
    [&$code_p_client,"Le champ code postal client n'est pas valide",$apply1],
    [&$code_p_boutique,"Le champ code postal boutique n'est pas valide",$apply1],
    [&$another_var,"Error message for this var",function(&$v) {$v = 123;}],
    //...
];

$messages = [];
$preg = '/^[\d]{5}$/';
array_walk($arProcess,function($a) use ($preg,&$messages) {
    if ( is_string($a[0]) && preg_match($preg,$a[0]) ) {
        if (is_callable($a[2]) )
            $a[2]($a[0]);
    } else {
        $messages[] = $a[1];
    }
});

if (count($messages)) {
    // wrong input
    var_dump($messages);
} else {
    // do stuff
    echo 'OK';
}

?>
```